# Doubt between power consumption and flow of current

Tags: electricity, electric-current, power

Suppose we have two electrical element say A and B where A having greater resistance than B , So here we say that power consumption of A is greater than B ,but when they are connected to seperate circuit ,the circuit containing A will draw less current than B . Why is it so??

Comment: "here we say that power consumption of A is greater than B"  under what conditions?  How are they wired?

Comment: Less current will flow through a circuit with A connected because A effects current flow more than B. If you had no resistance at all you would have pretty large current but there would be no circuit elements that effect current flow and no power consumption in any device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no contradiction between the two situations. When the elements are in the same circuit in line, they conduct the same intensity i of current and as the power consumed by a resistance is P =Ri2 the larger the resistance the larger the power consumed. Power consumption is not an intrinsic property. When the elements are separeted they indeed conduct different intensities the larger the resistance the smaller the current. Their power consumption is still calculated with P=RI2.